# I need to draw a chord in d3 in eclipse shape rather as circle

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, chord-diagram

Here is my sample js file i need to draw a chord but in eclipse shape rather then a circle. Secondly i need to know that what is a matrix use while creating chord diagram and are we able to draw a chord with simple json file (without using matrix) as mentioned http://www.delimited.io/blog/2013/12/8/chord-diagrams-in-d3 here. Because in every example of chord some matrix is give to draw it. I am new to d3 i need to learn lot of things. Can any one help really appreciate it

```
var outerRadius = 500 / 2,
innerRadius = outerRadius - 100;

var fill = d3.scale.category20c();

var chord = d3.layout.chord()
.padding(.04)
.sortSubgroups(d3.descending)
.sortChords(d3.descending);

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
.innerRadius(innerRadius)
.outerRadius(innerRadius + 20);

var svg = d3.select('#content').append("svg")
.attr("width", outerRadius * 2)
.attr("height", outerRadius * 2)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + outerRadius + "," + outerRadius +      

")");


d3.json("readme.json", function(error, imports) {
if (error) throw error;

var indexByName = d3.map(),
  nameByIndex = d3.map(),
  matrix = [],
  n = 0;

// Returns the Flare package name for the given class name.
function name(name) {
return name.substring(0, name.lastIndexOf(".")).substring(6);
}

// Compute a unique index for each package name.
imports.forEach(function(d) {
if (!indexByName.has(d = name(d.name))) {
  nameByIndex.set(n, d);
  indexByName.set(d, n++);
}
});

 // Construct a square matrix counting package imports.
 imports.forEach(function(d) {
  var source = indexByName.get(name(d.name)),
    row = matrix[source];
  if (!row) {
  row = matrix[source] = [];
  for (var i = -1; ++i < n;) row[i] = 0;
}
  d.imports.forEach(function(d) { row[indexByName.get(name(d))]++; });
  });

 chord.matrix(matrix);

 var g = svg.selectAll("g.group")
   .data(chord.groups())
   .enter().append("svg:g")
   .attr("class", "group")

 .on("mouseover", fade(.02))
    .on("mouseout", fade(.80));
 //  .on("mouseover", mouseover);
   //.on("mouseout", fade(1));

  g.append("svg:path")
    .style("stroke", "none")
    .style("fill", function(d) { return fill(d.index); })
    .attr("d", arc);
/* g.append("path")
  .style("fill", function(d) { return fill(d.index); })
  .style("stroke", function(d) { return fill(d.index); })
  .attr("d", arc);*/

    g.append("text")
    .each(function(d) { d.angle = (d.startAngle + d.endAngle) / 2; })
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "rotate(" + (d.angle * 180 / Math.PI - 90) + ")"
    + "translate(" + (innerRadius + 26) + ")"
    + (d.angle > Math.PI ? "rotate(180)" : "");
    })
   .style("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.angle > Math.PI ?   "end" : null; })
  .text(function(d) { return nameByIndex.get(d.index); });

  svg.selectAll(".chord")
  .data(chord.chords)
 .enter().append("path")
  .attr("class", "chord")
  .style("stroke", function(d) { return  
  d3.rgb(fill(d.source.index)).darker(); })
  .style("fill", function(d) { return fill(d.source.index); })
//.style("opacity", 1)
  .attr("d", d3.svg.chord().radius(innerRadius));

 });


  d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", outerRadius * 5 +   "px");
```

Comment: what is an eclipse shape may be you can elaborate that ...in the example you pasted you are reading from json d3.json("readme.json", ...i dont understand what you mean by matrx here.

Comment: https://github.com/sghall/d3-chord-diagrams/blob/master/uber.html in this example see data is called from two files .defer(d3.json, 'data/uber-matrix.json') and   .defer(d3.csv, 'data/uber-cities.csv') so i need to know that what is this matrix file? Secondly chord is always drawn in circular shape i need to draw a chord but in oval shape rest will be same as chord looks like.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
  #tooltip {
    color: white;
    opacity: .9;
    background: #333;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    visibility: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
  #circle circle {
    fill: none;
    pointer-events: all;
  }
  path.group {
    fill-opacity: .8;
  }
  path.chord {
    fill-opacity: .8;
    stroke: #000;
    stroke-width: .25px;
  }
  #circle:hover path.fade {
    display: none;
  }
</style>
    </head>
   <body>
<div id="tooltip"></div>
<script src="lib/d3.js"></script>
<script src="lib/underscore.js"></script>
<script src="js/mapper.js"></script>
<script>


 //*******************************************************************
  //  CREATE MATRIX AND MAP

 //*******************************************************************
  d3.csv('data/CNV.csv', function (error, data) {


    var mpr = chordMpr(data);

    mpr
      .addValuesToMap('chr_no')
      .addValuesToMap('MUT')

    mpr  .setFilter(function (row, a, b) {
        return (row.chr_no === a.name && row.MUT === b.name) ||
               (row.chr_no === b.name && row.MUT === a.name)

      })
      .setAccessor(function (recs, a, b) {
        if (!recs[0]) return 0;
          return recs[0].MUT === a.name ? +recs[0].chr_start :    
  +recs[0].chr_stop ; 
      });
    drawChords(mpr.getMatrix(), mpr.getMap());
  });


 //*******************************************************************
  //  DRAW THE CHORD DIAGRAM

//*******************************************************************
  function drawChords (matrix, mmap) {
    var w = 980, h = 800, r1 = h / 2, r0 = r1 - 110;

    var fill = d3.scale.ordinal()

  .range(['#c7b570','#c6cdc7','#335c64','#768935',
  '#507282','#5c4a56','#aa7455','#574109','#837722',
'#73342d','#0a5564','#9c8f57','#7895a4','#4a5456',
'#b0a690','#0a3542',]);

    var chord = d3.layout.chord()
        .padding(.04)
        .sortSubgroups(d3.descending)
        .sortChords(d3.descending);

    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .innerRadius(r0)
        .outerRadius(r0 + 20);

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h)
      .append("svg:g")
        .attr("id", "circle")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + w / 2 + "," + h / 2 + ")");

        svg.append("circle")
            .attr("r", r0 + 20);

    var rdr = chordRdr(matrix, mmap);
    chord.matrix(matrix);

    var g = svg.selectAll("g.group")
        .data(chord.groups())
      .enter().append("svg:g")
        .attr("class", "group")
        .on("mouseover", mouseover)
        .on("mouseout", function (d) {    
  d3.select("#tooltip").style("visibility", "hidden") });

    g.append("svg:path")
        .style("stroke", "black")
        .style("fill", function(d) { return fill(rdr(d).gname); })
        .attr("d", arc);

    g.append("svg:text")
        .each(function(d) { d.angle = (d.startAngle + d.endAngle) / 2;      
     })
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .style("font-family", "helvetica, arial, sans-serif")
        .style("font-size", "9px")
        .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.angle > Math.PI ? 
       "end" : null; })
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "rotate(" + (d.angle * 180 / Math.PI - 90) + ")"
              + "translate(" + (r0 + 26) + ")"
              + (d.angle > Math.PI ? "rotate(180)" : "");
        })
        .text(function(d) { return rdr(d).gname; });

      var chordPaths = svg.selectAll("path.chord")
            .data(chord.chords())
          .enter().append("svg:path")
            .attr("class", "chord")
            .style("stroke", function(d) { return 
       d3.rgb(fill(rdr(d).sname)).darker(); })
            .style("fill", function(d) { return fill(rdr(d).sname); })
            .attr("d", d3.svg.chord().radius(r0))
            .on("mouseover", function (d) {
              d3.select("#tooltip")
                .style("visibility", "visible")
                .html(chordTip(rdr(d)))
                .style("top", function () { return (d3.event.pageY - 
       170)+"px"})
                .style("left", function () { return (d3.event.pageX - 
           100)+"px";})
            })
            .on("mouseout", function (d) { 
         d3.select("#tooltip").style("visibility", "hidden") });


      function chordTip (d) {

  var p = d3.format(".0%"), q = d3.format("0d")
        return "Choromosome information:<br/>"
          + q(d.sname) + " overlap with " + d.tname +"  " +
 "<br/>chromosome starts at"+" "+ d.sdata +"  " +
 "<br/>chromosome ends at"+ " "+ d.tdata

      }


      }

      function mouseover(d, i) {
        d3.select("#tooltip")
          .style("visibility", "visible")
          .html(groupTip(rdr(d)))
          .style("top", function () { return (d3.event.pageY - 80)+"px"})
          .style("left", function () { return (d3.event.pageX - 130)+"px";})

        chordPaths.classed("fade", function(p) {
          return p.source.index != i
              && p.target.index != i;
        });
      }
  }

</script>
```

Comment: Here is my code in this code i map chr_start, chr_stop,chr_no and MUT. What i want is to show rest of the fields which are in csv file as a tool tip information. I am drawing chord first time and i have no idea how to do that. In node graph we use to call specific field as d.name etc. now in chord graph how i can get rest of the values I have property, name, age in csv to appear as a tooltip. thakns in advance